# How to get class name from .cs file with other information by Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am new in regex expression. I need to write a regexp code which find all the class with it's specifier, type (abstract, static) and its base classes.

Let say if my Customer.cs file has following code

```
 internal class Customer
{
 //stuff
}
public class XYZ : Customer
    ,IServiceProvider
{
    private class Order
    {
 //stuff
    }
}

public abstract class ABC
{ 
     //stuff
}
public static class ABC1
{ 
     //stuff
}
```

How can i get all the class names in following format by Regexp

```
internal class Customer
 public class XYZ : Customer
        ,IServiceProvider
private class Order
public abstract class ABC
public static class ABC1
```

I can't use reflection for this purpose.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want this to be 100% guaranteed then you simply need to get your hands dirty and write a proper parser for the subset of C# that interests you (or possibly use [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/roslyn) to do the work for you). Otherwise you have to accept the possibility of some false positives, in which case you haven't said what your tolerance is.

Comment: Thanks @Jon for your valuable comment, I'll try to write parser for this.

Answer (score 4):

If you knew that the code you were parsing was valid you could use:

```
const string Code = @"internal class Customer..."; //code to parse goes here

const string pattern = @"(((internal)|(public)|(private)|(protected)|(sealed)|(abstract)|(static))?[\s\r\n\t]+){0,2}class[\s\S]+?(?={)";

var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(Code, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

var classes = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value.Trim());
```

You may want to do a bit of cleanup on the result - i.e. remove new lines

Comment: this is a very good regex. You should just remove RegexOptions.IgnoreCase because if your namespace contains the word Class it will be recognized as a classname.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following Regex...

```
.*?\sclass\s[\S\s]*?(?={)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would need to handle:

1. The fact that eg static, sealed or abstract and private, internal or public may or may not be present and can be in any order.
2. You may falsely find @class variables within the code.
3. The patterns you are trying to match may be spread across many lines.

It may be possible to write such a regex, but it would be ridiculously complex and unreliable if you could. You are trying to find things within a non-regular grammar and therefore regexes are not the solution. You need a proper grammar parser.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code is correct (i.e. it compiles with no problems) you don't need a regexp, splitting gets the job done:

```
var code = "<Your code goes in here"; // SEE BELOW
var classDeclarations = code
     .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
     .Split('{', '}')
     .Where(c => c.Contains("class");
```

What code does:

1. Remove all newlines to pack things up
2. Split on braces
3. Hunt classes down

For the code to behave properly, you either should:

1. Copy-Paste it in the string (awful, but effective): you should replace all `"` with `\"` in this case
2. Load from file in string: quotes should be handled automagically but keep an eye on it